# Get records from Generic Object using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5.2

I have generic object and I need to get item {code, description} from it using LINQ Query

### Class

```
  [Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Genders")]
public class Gender
{

    [XmlElement("Genders")]
    public List<GenderListWrap> GenderListWrap = new List<GenderListWrap>();       
}


public class GenderListWrap
{
    [XmlAttribute("list")]
    public string ListTag { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> GenderList = new List<Item>();
}



public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

here in following screen shot I see my data in GenderObject

[image]

Comment: Can't you cast it to `(Gender)`?

Comment: Do you want to get a list of items or a specific item? Your screenshot indicates there is more than 1.

Comment: What´s your problem?

Comment: Looks like you can access it. GenderObject.GenderListWrap[0].GenderList[1]

Comment: I want to get GenderList...

Comment: var genderList = GenderObject.GenderListWrap[0];

Comment: i can hard code but this is just example, for other xml I need linq

Comment: why negative marking?

Comment: Well, if you know the type only at runtime, you need reflection to get access to the `GenderList`-property on the `GenderWrap`-instance.

Comment: "why negative marking?" I suppose because "**it does not show any research-effort**, it is unclear or not usefull".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** EDIT ***

Based on your edits, it appears your issue is related to the datatype you are receiving from your "ObjectToXML" method - this returns something of type `Object` by the looks of your code, not something of the type you have specified in your question. You could try to cast to the expected type `eg. Gender GenderObject = (Gender)SystemCore.XMLPrasing.ObjectToXML(...)`, which *may* fail (if the returned type isn't actually Gender). Or you could use the .NET built in XML deserialization, which will be able to return objects of the correct type.

---

Despite the rather odd data structure you have (whay such effort for a list of genders?), if you want a `List<Item>`, the following will project just the items into a list:

```
genders.GenderListWrap.SelectMany(l => l.GenderList).ToList();
```

(This is assuming you have an instance called `genders`, constructed something like:

```
var genders = new Gender
{
    GenderListWrap = new List<GenderListWrap>
    {
        new GenderListWrap
        {
            GenderList = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Code = "F", Description = "Female" },
                new Item { Code = "M", Description = "Male" },
            }
        },
        new GenderListWrap
        {
            GenderList = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Code = "N", Description = "Neutral" },
            }
        }
    }
};

var genderList = genders.GenderListWrap.SelectMany(l => l.GenderList).ToList();
```

If, however, you want to get a specific item, you can just use the standard index accessors mentioned in comments, eg. `genders.GenderListWrap[0].GenderList[0]`

Comment: I guess the OPs problem is that he/she doesn´t know what `genders` is at compile-time. See how `GenderObject` is defined, it obviously was created at runtime from a method returning just an `object`.

Comment: I am using generic class to deserialize coming xml string and type. hence in later stage I need to convert or read data as specific class type

Comment: Gender is just simple example to implement logic

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, if you cast the object you have to Gender and then do a select on it:

```
var genderList = ((Gender)GenderObject).GenderListWrap.SelectMany(x => x.GenderList);
```

This will return a collection of `Item`s on which you will have the *{code, description}*  you are looking for.